# What are the disadvantages of my implementation of the builder object?

Tags: java, oop, builder

I want to know if my implementation of the builder object has disadvantages compared to the builder object implementation I see on most site's. I know it's overkill to implement a builder object for a class with only 2 fields, but these are just examples and meant to be small.

My implementation:

```
public class User {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    private User(){}

    public static class Builder{

        private final User user;

        public Builder(){
            user = new User();
        }

        public Builder firstname(String firstname){
            user.firstname = firstname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder lastname(String lastname){
            user.lastname = lastname;
            return this;
        }

        public User build(){
            return user;
        }   
    }
}
```

Builder object as found on the internet ([example1](http://javarevisited.blogspot.be/2012/06/builder-design-pattern-in-java-example.html) [example2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html)):

```
public class User {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    private User(Builder builder){
        this.firstname = builder.firstname;
        this.lastname = builder.lastname;
    }

    public static class Builder{

        private String firstname;

        private String lastname;

        public Builder firstname(String firstname){
            this.firstname = firstname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder lastname(String lastname){
            this.lastname = lastname;
            return this;
        }

        public User build(){
            return new User(this);
        }   
    }
}
```

The second implementations seems cumbersome, cause the builder needs to have exactly the same field as the object it will be building (read: writing the same code twice).
It also seems more naturally (to me) that the builder creates the new `User` and populates its fields, instead off calling the constructor of the `User` with it's own instance.

Both examples can be tested with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u = new User.Builder().firstname("Tom").lastname("Jonckheere").Build();
        System.out.println(u.getFirstname());
        System.out.println(u.getLastname());
    }
```

So my question is:
What are the disadvantages of my implementation of the builder object? I can't really tell any (and I'm not saying there aren't any) so I would like to hear some feedback! Or is my code also a valid implementation of the builder object?

Comment: This would probably be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The second one allows  you to reuse the builder (imagine you have some field on `User` set on instantiation), not the first

Comment: In your own solution, the fields in `User` are not `final` so they can potentially be modified.

Comment: Your solution might be nice without the `Builder` class, so that you'd have a fluent set of setters on the `User` itself. Then it's easy to see what it does and does not have the surprising error hidden in it.

Comment: @Jesper, and why do they need to be `final`? Imagine (I know it's far fetched!) that I want to change my name?

Comment: @TomJonckheere Then you shouldn't be using a builder (which is made to create immutable classes - those fith final fields and no setters / mutators of any kind). If you want to change names, simply leave the user as mutable. You can have fluent setters (`new User().firstName("Jack").lastName("Smith")`) if you want.

Comment: @Slanec, I see! Thanks for the explenation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in the implementations are that if you want to create multiple equal (or similar) but not same objects, you'll have to create a new `Builder` whereas with the other implementation you can do this:

```
Builder b = new User.Builder();
User john = b.firstName("John").lastName("Smith").build();
User jack = b.firstName("Jack").build();
```

Comment: Indeed, they are all called Jack Smith :-) I (wrongly) tested this, I modified all fields...